# Can I use some GitHub control/Framework with MIT / BSD / Apache Licence to distribute my iOS Enterprise App?

Tags: ios, github, mit-license, bsd-license, apache-license

I develop iOS app with some GitHub controls and Framework as like FMDB,AFNetworking,OpenCV,RadioButton,CheckBoX etc... but now my worry is I want to distribute this app with Apple Enterprise account (not on app store).

I already read some post which say we can use to distribute app with these licence but they were in web plugins but I'm using to distribute iOS enterprise app , so can you please suggest whether is there any problem to use these control/framework if yes what precaution do I need to take ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a lawyer, and I'm not familiar with all of the regulations which Apple places on Apple Enterprise applications, but from my understanding of these licenses:

As long as you are able to comply with the conditions of the individual licenses, it should be perfectly fine for you to distribute the application. All of the licenses which you listed are "permissive" licenses, which means that you can just include the license/copyright notices in your app somewhere. Many applications have some kind of "About" page that has a list of all the open source licenses it uses. There are some additional (and very simple) conditions that may apply if you modify the Apache-licensed libraries and distribute copies of the modified source code, but that shouldn't be an issue in your case.

Comment: Thanks for answer @blm768....so according to your comment, I'm not taking any ownership/copyrights of these control/framework I'm just using in my app and want to distribute that app. and yes I also don't think this will create any issue but just to get all you guys reviews on it and some helpful comments or thoughts(for precaution).